# How to record audio over Powerpoint/OpenOffice slides?

Tags: audio, screen-capture, quicktime

Many times I've seen videos of people talking while presenting their slides. How is that done on a Mac?

I know that I can do a screen recording with Quicktime, and I notice there are two options New Screen Recording and New Audio Recording.

But there is no New Screen+Audio Recording.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually record audio with a Screen Recording in Quicktime, you just need to set the proper option. Just open a new screen recording (⌃⌘N), then click the white triangle:

[image: Screen Recording]

You'll get a popup menu with options to choose which sound input you want to record from:
[image: Recording Options]

Select the appropriate sound device, then start the recoding, and you'll be able to narrate as you record your screen.

Answer (score 0):

The type of software you want is called Screen Casting. There are many apps which do this, but it's usually the paid ones which offer unlimited recording with audio, although I'm sure there's something out there which will suit your needs.

I used to use one called [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html), but having just looked, there's a 5 minute limit on creating the videos for free. They have a newer premium package called [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) on there.